# AssertionError and assert

Tags: java, exception, assert, throwable

I'm preparing for OCP 7, and I encountered this essay on one of that certificate books.

> To discourage you from trying to substitute an assertion for an
>   exception, the AssertionError doesn’t provide access to the object
>   that generated it. All you get is the String message.

I tried a lot of possibilities to conduct what is being said but I found no difference on `AssertionError` with others.

Can you explain to me what that quote means?

Answer (score 3):

The explanation can be found in [the FAQ in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#design-faq-error) of the `assert` keyword:

> **Why doesn't an AssertionError allow access to the object that generated it? Similarly, why not pass an arbitrary object from the assertion to the AssertionError constructor in place of a detail message?**
>
> Access to these objects would encourage programmers to attempt to recover from assertion failures, which defeats the purpose of the facility.

Consider the following code:

```
int i = 0;
assert i != 0 : "i must not be zero"
```

If assertions are enabled, this will throw an `AssertionError` with a message initialized to `"i must not be zero"`. But that is all this error will contain. If it would contain more information, it would encourage developers to somehow recover from the error by catching the `AssertionError`. In theory, it is still possible to inspect the error message and try to do something with it but then you are really going against every good practice.

Comment: That doesn't explain because AssertionError class has inherited methods from Throwable without adding or overriding anything like IOException for example.

Comment: @Aladdin There is a difference between throwing an `AssertionError` yourself, and the one thrown automatically by `assert` keyword. If you throw it yourself, you can give it an object, but the `assert` keyword won't do that.